# AnnotationSessionFactoryBean and singleton scoped bean (Spring framework)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, session

I define a bean of type AnnotationSessionFactoryBean for using in a web-app.

If I do not explicitly define it as NOT singleton, it must be singleton.

Now, it is bound to the current thread.

It means it cannot be a singleton.

p.s. Session produced by Factory is not a singleton, SessionFactory on the other hand is always a singleton. Now everything is clear!

Answer (score 2):

The `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` (its superclass) defines the `isSingleton()` method which returns true. So the `SessionFactory` returned by this factory bean *is* singleton.

On the other hand, the `Session` that the `SessionFactory` produces may be thread-bound.

So you have:

```
BeanFactory creates SessionFactory creates Session
```

Comment: Right, that's only a FACTORY! Spring simplifies the matter to such a degree that sometimes one can miss the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The superclass of `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` called `LocalSessionFactoryBean` has some `ThreadLocal<?>` static fields:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<DataSource> configTimeDataSourceHolder =
        new ThreadLocal<DataSource>();

private static final ThreadLocal<TransactionManager> configTimeTransactionManagerHolder =
        new ThreadLocal<TransactionManager>();

private static final ThreadLocal<Object> configTimeRegionFactoryHolder =
        new ThreadLocal<Object>();

private static final ThreadLocal<CacheProvider> configTimeCacheProviderHolder =
        new ThreadLocal<CacheProvider>();

private static final ThreadLocal<LobHandler> configTimeLobHandlerHolder =
        new ThreadLocal<LobHandler>();
```

So even a single instance of this bean might interact differently in different threads.

Comment: really? Well yes, it is a complex object. Thank you